# How can I only clear the previous cells highlighted from this code in excel?

Tags: excel

I found this code to insert into excel to highlight certain cells after you cick on a cell.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'Set the context appropriately using With...End With
With Sheets("calendar")

    'Clear all previously-applied highlighting for easy readability
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    'Switch on the address of the selected cell
    Select Case Target.Address
    
        Case "$A$1" '<~ if cell A1 is clicked, highlight cells C5-C9 yellow
            .Range("C5:C9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            
        Case "$A$2" '<~ if cell A2 is clicked, highlight cell D5-D9 green
            .Range("D5:D9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            
        Case "$A$3" '<~ if cell A3 is clicked, highlight cell E5-E9 orange
            .Range("E5:E9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
            
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that it clears ALL highlight in the worksheet. I only want to clear the highlight after the selected cell is no longer selected.

Comment: Then change `.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone` this line like `.Range(...).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! this worked like a charm. Do you know how I can change the "case" line, instead of one cell selected, I would like a range of cells selected to highlight another part of the worksheet

Comment: @Harun24HR sorry forgot to @ you

Answer (score 0):

Below codes will run if you do action with range `A2:D5`. You can change this range as your own need.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then   
    Range("C5:C9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)   
End If
```